# Vim deleting multiple words

Tags: vim

Earlier I was in a situation where I wanted to delete 3 words, with the cursor inside of the first one. For example

> Vim is the best text editor

with the cursor on the `h` in `the`. I wanted to end up at

> Vim is editor

I tried using 3diw to get rid of them, but that left me with

> Vim is  text editor

with 2 spaces between `is` and `text`. `3daw` worked fine, leaving me with what I wanted, but I'm confused about why `3diw` didn't work. I would have expected `3diw` and `3daw` to delete the same number of words, and have the only difference be `diw` leave two spaces and `daw` leave one.

So why does `3diw` have this behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you didn't understand the difference between `iw` and `aw`. with `[count]diw` (inner words), spaces between words would be counted as well. but they won't be counted with `aw`

```
iw          "inner word", select [count] words (see |word|).
            White space between words is counted too.
            When used in Visual linewise mode "iw" switches to
            Visual characterwise mode.

                            *v_aW* *aW*
aW          "a WORD", select [count] WORDs (see |WORD|).
            Leading or trailing white space is included, but not
            counted.
```

so if you want to do with `iw` with your example, you need press `6diw`:

```
1 the
2 " "
3 best
4 " "
5 text
6 " "
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I hadn't realized that the inner spaces would be counted as words.